# Replace a word that has a specific format with another format

Tags: linux

I want to replace the space between c and 2 ('C 2',) with two spaces as 'C 2', I tried with sed -i but it does not work
sed -i 's/'C 2',/'C  2',/g' test.dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes stop the quoting. Either change the quoting or escape it.

You could do it like so:

```
sed -i 's/'\''C 2'\'',/'\''C  2'\'',/g' test.dat
```

The `'\''` stop the quoting, escape a single quote and then continue with quoting.

But for your specific case, you could just use double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/'C 2',/'C  2',/g" test.dat
```